# vmware tools support in Ubuntu 11.04 guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, vmware-tools

I have been trying to get vmware tools support successfully configured and started in my Ubuntu 11.04 guest. I am running a current version of vmware workstation on Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate with an Ubuntu 11.04 guest install. This VM was created using the easyinstall option in vmware workstation.

I have manually reinstalled and reconfigured vmware tools with the follwoing results.

last bit of relevant output following the vmware-config-tools.pl execution.

```
Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
initctl: Job failed to start
Unable to start services for VMware Tools
```

syslog output following reboot when vmware tools service fials

```
Jun 21 17:44:33 ubuntu tpvmlpd[17011]: bad device "/dev/**" given
Jun 21 17:44:33 ubuntu init: vmware-tools pre-start process (16816) terminated with status 1
```

I am hoping someone has some ideas.. Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-virtual
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends open-vm-dkms
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
sudo vmware-toolbox
```

Comment: This had no effect. Same error message in syslog.

Comment: I had already installed all this as well, same error.. I have also traded emails with vmware's linux tools point of contact and still have not gotten past this issue. They just have poor support for Linux guests.

Comment: @apesa: Give my answer a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

The error in question is from the ThinPrint service, which you most likely (99% of cases) don't need at all. You can easily (and safely) disable it. Edit `/etc/init.d/vmware-tools` using your favorite text editor (which we all know is Vim) and comment out `/usr/bin/tpvmlpd`. Then restart it by running `/etc/init.d/vmware-tools restart`.

Comment: The file (vmware-tools) does not exist (at least on my VM). Is that expected? From where else would the ThinPrint drivers be started?